the old node-gyp cannot recognized vs2022
I have an old project that uses NPM6. Even though I upgraded node to version 23, npm to version 10.9, and node gyp to version 10.2.0, node gyp still automatically uses version 7.1.2 during npm installation.
Then I used the vsinstall tool to install vs2022, and also installed the MSVS packages for 2017 and 2015.
but，The problem now is that there are always errors reported in the screenshot belowenter image description here
And if I upgrade the package to be able to recognize VS2022, other dependencies also need to be upgraded. I have upgraded many versions of dependencies in package.json, but it is difficult to compile them
I have tried many solutions, but to no avail.
Now I feel that as long as the old version of node gyp can find vs2017, it's good.
But what should I do?
